# jQuery and Grails/HTML - Make text field complete text like Google does

Tags: jquery, html, grails, autocomplete

I wanna make certain fields in my page to show me like a list of possible finishing sentences just like Google does.

I think this is done via jQuery, but I'm not sure.

The textfield is named commodity.

Let's say I write General and in the list, array, or DB I have General Commodity I should show me General Commodity under the textfield.

Thanks in advance!

-------UPDATE-------

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js">
var data = "General Commodity,General Store,General Custer,General Mills".split(",");

    $("#Ccommodity").autocomplete({
            source: data
        });
</script>
```

When I go to the Ccommodity input textfield I write G and nothing happens, maybe I have some syntax error there.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will probably want to look into the [jQueryUI Autocomplete widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).  It has several ways of providing lists of suggestions, and there will almost certainly be something in there that will work for you.

Here's a very basic demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QU9st/

Here's the source for that:

```
$(function() {
    var data = "General Commodity,General Store,General Custer,General Mills".split(",");
    $("#commodity").autocomplete({
            source: data
        });
});
```

That demo simply uses a static string array as the datasource, but you can also use remote datasources, in formats like JSON or XML.

To get it, just drop this somewhere in your `<head>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Of course, you will also need to include jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for. Do I need to install the jquery-ui plugin for Grails?

Comment: Yes, you need to specifically include jQueryUI on your page. You can download it from their site or grab a link to it from Google's code repository here: http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html

Comment: How do I install jQuery UI in Grails?

Comment: You don't really "install" it.  It's a javascript library, just like jQuery.  You just have to include it on your page with a script tag.

Comment: And put it where? Because I know there is a jQuery UI Plugin for Grails, but I'm not sure if it is the same http://www.grails.org/plugin/jquery-ui

Comment: Like, I don't know if I really need to install the plugin, or just download the js library and put it somewhere.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Admittedly, I don't know anything about Grails, but yes, I think that the plug-in you linked will suit your needs. You shouldn't really need the plug-in though.  Probably the easiest thing to do is just link to the copy of it that Google hosts. I'll edit my answer to show how that's done.

Comment: For some reason is not working... Maybe I'm doing something wrong... I'll update the question with some code so you can see

Comment: Yes, I have other jQuery functions working. Specially on (document).ready

Comment: But again, I don't need that, by installing the plugin and putting the tag <g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery" /> It loads the jQuery plugin, which is the same as putting it the HTML way. But that's why I'm having problems with the jQuery UI plugin, because UI is a plugin of jQuery.

Comment: It looks like you haven't wrapped the call to autocomplete in $(function() { });  (which is the shorthand for (document).ready).  Perhaps that is the problem?

Comment: The thing is that Grails has the prototype library by default, and by using the $(function{} ..... ) it reads the prototype $, not the jQuery one. I'll check and let you know.

Comment: No, it loads perfectly, like no errors on the page, but nothing happens when I write in the txtfield :/

Comment: $ is just an alias for jQuery, so you can do jQuery(function() { }); as well.

Comment: I know, I read that somewhere too. But no. I changed it and nothing is happening :S

Comment: I'm all out of ideas then :( Sorry!

Comment: I think I know what the problems is. Because I'm using grails and it creates a list of objects, and all the elements in the list are textfields so I had two with the same name, the creating one, and the first one on the list. Lemme see if its that. Thanks!

Comment: OK :D!!!! I got it to work, but it doesn't work on the first one. I think is a conflict with the IDs.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery has an [Autocomplete widget](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete) That can get it to do what you want it to do. here's an example:
jQuery:

```
var data = "Core Selectors Attributes Traversing Manipulation CSS Events Effects Ajax".split(" ");
$("#commodity").autocomplete(data);
```

html:

```
<input type="text" id="commodity" name="commodity">
```

Comment: Do I need to install jQuery-UI plugin for Grails, or it comes already with the jQuery plugin?

Comment: This is seperate from jQueryUI, and doesn't require any further installation besides the plug in itself. that's why I included a different answer from @Ender

Comment: The plug-in is deprecated.  The jQueryUI is the successor of this plug-in.