# jQuery Autocomplete/predict - like google

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am looking to create a search feature similar to google using jQuery. however, I am unsure of the name of one of its features.

The feature in question is the text prediction element.

eg. if I type jquery it shows in the input box "Jquery" as my input but then in grey it adds the text of the first result in the input box and allows the user to select this "predictive value"

I have searched high and low for the name of this functionality and a working example.

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I guess this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875079/jquery-and-grails-html-make-text-field-complete-text-like-google-does (here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/QU9st/)

Comment: Maybe it? http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/

Comment: You should try [jqueryui autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).

Comment: Almost! but not quite like that, it needs to be entered into the input box with its own style, the issue I am having is styling the suggestion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for an auto complete feature. jQuery UI has an awesome autocomplete feature included in it.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

The result of your search you can get from an array or a database table (thru a server page).It is quite simple to set up as below

The below example is using an array as data source for the auto suggest items.

```
$(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "Scheme"
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
```

The above code binds the textbox with id "tags" to the autocomplete function. we mentioned the source value as the name of our array where we stored different programming language names.

Mostly, you may need to get data from a database, then you use an intermediate server page as datasource. this server page will get data from the data access layer and give you the result.

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: "searchtags.php",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                log( ui.item ?
                    "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
            }
        });
```

Comment: Just an update Guys, I understand the Jquery UI autocomplete plugin and that is functionality I am adding, however this question is asking how to create the greyed out suggested text in the INPUT box. I would upload a screen shot but SO wont allow me to.

Comment: @Coops :To have the different style suggested text, you simply update the CSS style for that item. Use firebug to findout what is the current style and update the CSS there. thats it

Comment: Tried that, however you can only style the who input, not portions of text within it. hence looking for a javascript solution

Comment: You can style however you want the autocomplete plugin. just update the styles to reflect bg color changes for the result/ selected item etc. no javascript needed. It should be only css change

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking is autocomplete plugin. There are a several, but the 'official one' is this jquery autocomplete : http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete and the code :

```
$("#example").autocomplete(data);
```

Comment: No, it's the [jQuery UI one](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) now. But I've still got some projects running that one (the bassistance.de one)